# Nested foreach binding not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to display an `observableArray` within an `observableArray`.

It's a simple ToDo list where the tasks are assigned to certain people and I want to display each persons tasks in there own div.

I'm using knockoutjs 3.3.0

Why aren't the Tasks showing up under the person?

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div>
      <form data-bind="submit: addPerson">
        <p>New Person: <input data-bind='value: personToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
          <button type="submit" data-bind="enable: personToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
        </p>
      </form>
      <form data-bind="submit: addTask">
        <p>New Task: <input data-bind='value: taskToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
          <select data-bind="options: people, optionsText: 'name', value:selectedPerson"></select>
          <button type="submit" data-bind="enable: taskToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
        </p>
      <fieldset>
      <legend>Tasks</legend>
        <div data-bind="foreach: people">
          <div style="float: left; padding-right: 20px;">
            <label data-bind="text: name" />
            <div data-bind="foreach: tasks">
              <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: done" />
              <label data-bind="text: description, style: { textDecoration: done() ? 'line-through' : 'none' }" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
    var ToDoList = function (people) {
    var self = this;

    self.taskToAdd = ko.observable("");
    self.personToAdd = ko.observable("");
    self.selectedPerson = ko.observable("");
    self.people = ko.observableArray(people);

    self.addTask = function () {
      if (self.taskToAdd() != "") {

        var person = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.people(), function (item) {
          return item.name() === self.selectedPerson().name();
        });

        person.addTask(new Task(self.taskToAdd(), person.name()));

        self.taskToAdd("");
      }
    };

    self.addPerson = function () {
      if (self.personToAdd() != "") {
        self.people.push(new Person(self.personToAdd()));
        self.personToAdd("");
      }
    }.bind(self);
    };

    var Task = function (task, assignee) {
      var self = this;

      self.task = ko.observable(task);
      self.assignee = ko.observable(assignee)
      self.done = ko.observable(false);

      self.description = ko.pureComputed(function () {
      return self.task() + " (Assigned to: " + self.assignee() + ")";
      }, self);
    };

    var Person = function (name, tasks) {
      var self = this;

      self.name = ko.observable(name);
      self.tasks = ko.observableArray(tasks);

      self.addTask = function (task) {
      self.tasks.push(task);
      }.bind(self);
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new ToDoList());
```

Comment: simple try like this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/23415/ . fiddle is not fully functional once i get time i will get to it . cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the tasks are not appearing is because your `<label>` tags are not closed correctly. Instead of `<label data-bind="blah"/>`, use `<label data-bind="blah"></label>`.

The tasks container is not currently rendering at all, and therefore not parsed by knockout.

To be more clear, the label with data-bind="text: name" is not closed properly AND has a text binding. The text binding is replacing the entire tasks container with the name of the person. There are two instances of this error in your sample.

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't have caught that. And thanks for the explanation of why the label tag wasn't closed properly, it'll help me to be more careful in the future.